# Error OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound when accessing messages Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365

I get the error "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound" while trying to access to my inbox messages.

To explain I am trying to develop an app and in this app I need to access my inbox e-mails.
So I try to use the Outlook API and for that I created an APP with all demanded permissions "Email.Read, Email.ReadBasics, Emails.ReadAll...". I have an Office 365 Family subscription, and an active paid azure subscription. My question is why getting my personal information works '/users/{user-id}' but when accessing to emails I got this error ? I read a lot of docs and never get an answer... Maybe my subscription does not get me access to Microsoft Exchange Online License, or due to my old microsoft address "...@live.com" maybe it is not compatible, I dont't know, if someone can help me to clear it out, would be great. Oh, and abviously my Office 365 and Azure account are the same.

I tried, with 'client credentials flow authentication' (which give me the error 'need more privileges'), went back to Authorization Code Flow Atuhentication but then I get the OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound error. But only on /messages endpoint, the endpoint users/{user-id} works. Obviously I tried all threads I found, even with an Office 365 Developer account but don't really see the correlation with my problem here.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

**To resolve the error, try the below:**

I created an **Azure AD Application** and granted API permissions:

[image]

I generated **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

To resolve the error, I added **Microsoft Exchange Online License** as below:

[image]

After assigning the license, **I am able to get the messages of the user successfully** as below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserId/messages
```

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, check the below:

- Check if the authentication token is matching the Tenant.
- Check whether the User exists in the Tenant you are referring to.
- Make sure Microsoft Exchange Online License is assigned which is included in Microsoft 365 license.

**Reference:**

[Get message - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)